# Angularjs2 + Electron + Angularfire2

Tags: angular, electron, angularfire2

I'm trying to implement the Firebase access from a desktop app using AngularJS2 + Eletron.
I've downloaded the example "Electron + AngularJS2" from https://github.com/DenisVuyka/ng2-electron, it works very fine.

But after I add the Angularfire2 component, AngularJS starts to fail.
Basically I just did the follow steps after download the ng2-electron source:

**1. Installed the components:**

> npm install angularfire2 firebase --save

**2. Updated my app.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';

import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';


export const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxx",
    databaseURL: "https://xxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxx"
};


@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The follow error appears after these changes:
"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND", "Error: (SystemJS) XHR error loading"

[image: error]

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @5minutes2start suggestion I could fix my code.

So, the changes were made on file **systemjs.config.js**

I've added these 2 lines on map:

> 'angularfire2': 'npm:angularfire2', 
>   'firebase': 'npm:firebase',

and added these to packages:

> angularfire2: {
>      main: './bundles/angularFire2.umd.js',
>      defaultExtension: 'js'
>   },
>   firebase: {
>      main: './firebase.js',
>      defaultExtension: 'js'
>   }

My full **systemjs.config.js**:

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    map: {
      app: 'app',
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      ...

      'angularfire2': 'npm:angularfire2',
      'firebase': 'npm:firebase',
    },
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      angularfire2: {
        main: './bundles/angularFire2.umd.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      firebase: {
        main: './firebase.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }      
    }
  });
})(this);
```

After these changes another error appeared: *"Cannot read property 'FacebookAuthProvider' of undefined"*, I could fix it using the solution discussed here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/576

Add "firebase = firebase.firebase;" before "var _a = firebase.auth;" on **angularfire2.umd.js**

```
firebase = firebase.firebase; 
var _a = firebase.auth;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify systemjs.config.js
Add mapping for your new resource.

```
'angularfire2': 'npm:@angularfire2/bundles/angularfire2.umd.js'
```

Comment: Thanks @5minutes2start! Using your hint I could fix my code. I will share the whole changes below.